# SQL get sender due to value in table

Tags: sql-server

Hello Now I have 2 table .One of them is TEACHER, another INSTITUTE
I have a temp table #QUESTIONS. There are two row in this temp table

> QuestionId,SenderType,SenderId
>
> 1,Teacher,475
>
> 2,Institute,1

Now if sender type is teacher i want to get teacher name and surname from TEACHER table,if sender type is institute i want to get institute name from INSTITUTE table

How can I do it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Because i want a result for page like, question, sender name and receiver answer,so i need to reach this sender's name

Comment: are you using stored procedure and passing sender type as a parameter ??

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved using `UNION`

```
SELECT  q.SenderType ,
        t.Name + ' ' + t.Surname Name
FROM    #QUESTIONS q
        JOIN TEACHER t ON q.SenderId = t.ID
WHERE   q.SenderType = 'Teacher'

UNION ALL

SELECT  q.SenderType ,
        i.Name
FROM    #QUESTIONS q
        JOIN INSTITUTE i ON q.SenderId = i.ID
WHERE   q.SenderType = 'Institute';
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets try something different for this case. Look at the sample.

```
SELECT SENDERTYPE,Q.SENDERID,COALESCE(T.NAME,I.NAME) AS NAME,COALESCE(T.SURNAME,I.SURNAME) AS NAME FROM QUESTIONS Q
LEFT JOIN TEACHER T ON T.ID=Q.SENDERID AND Q.SENDERTYPE='TEACHER'
LEFT JOIN INSTITUTE I ON I.ID=Q.SENDERID AND Q.SENDERTYPE='INSTITUTE'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **CASE Statement**:

```
SELECT
    Q.QuestionId,
    Q.SenderType,
    CASE Q.SenderType WHEN 'Teacher' THEN T.Name+ ' '+T.Surname ELSE I.Name END AS Name
FROM @tblQuestion Q
LEFT JOIN @tblTeacher T ON Q.SenderId=T.Id AND Q.SENDERTYPE='TEACHER'
LEFT JOIN @tblInstitute I ON Q.SenderId=I.Id AND Q.SENDERTYPE='INSTITUTE'
```